# LWC combobox can't load values from custom object via apex controller

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm tring to load records from a custom object into a combobox for selection, but it is just blank.

component.html

```
<template>
    <div>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" >
        <lightning-combobox 
            name="prefix"
            label="prefix"
            value={value}
            placeholder="-Select-"
            options={countries}
            onchange={handleChange} >
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

component.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';

import getCountryPrefix from '@salesforce/apex/SMEBrokerRegistrationController.getCountryPrefix'

export default class test extends LightningElement {

    error;
    countries;
    prefix;

    connectedCallBack() {
        console.log('connectedCallBack');
        this.getCountries();
    }

    getCountries() {
        getCountryPrefix({})
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('result => ', JSON.stringify(result));
            this.countries = result.map((cls) => Object.assign({}, { label: cls.Name, value: cls.Name }));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('error => ', error); // error handling
        });
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target.name;
            this.prefix = event.target.value;
        }
        console.log('field = ' + field + ' = ' + event.target.value);
    }
}
```

apexController

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Country__c> getCountryPrefix() {
        system.debug('country method');
        return [
            SELECT Id, Name, Alt_Names__c, Dial_Code__c, Flag_Code__c 
            FROM Country__c
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ORDER BY Name 
       ];
    }
```

I have more to do with those records once I have them loaded in some aspect, I need to add icons from a static resource, but this is the starting point.

All help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed tracking the countries attribute.

Even though after [Spring '20](https://www.sfdconcept.com/post/lwc-the-track-decorator-is-no-longer-required-for-lightning-web-components) is no longer necessary to annotate attributes to automatically trigger re-renderization of LWC, **BUT** this only applies to simple types (strings, numbers booleans, etc). It is still necessary to track ARRAYS and OBJECTS

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';

import getCountryPrefix from '@salesforce/apex/YOUR_CONTROLLER.getCountryPrefix'

export default class Countries extends LightningElement {

    error;
    @track countries;
    prefix;

    @wire(getCountryPrefix)
    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('result => ', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.countries = data.map((cls) => Object.assign({}, { label: cls.Name, value: cls.Name }));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            console.error('error => ', error); // error handling
        }
    }
}
```

PD: I changed the component to use the wire method, which is the correct option

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score -1):

You should render the UI element when the data from the connectedcallback is ready.
Something like this:

```
<template>
<template if:true={countries}>
    <div>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" >
        <lightning-combobox 
            name="prefix"
            label="prefix"
            value={value}
            placeholder="-Select-"
            options={countries}
            onchange={handleChange} >
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello! The problem in his question is that he is not annotating the countries attribute